# childNodes property giving incorrect results?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to learn more about the DOM and have been writing some traversal scripts. The algorithm I've come up with worked fine for part of what I was doing, but when I applied it to the whole body of the HTML document it got messed up. Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Lumen Tests</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../qunit/qunit.css' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='qunit'></div>
        <div id='qunit-fixture'></div>

        <div id='wrapper'>
            <div id='header'></div>
            <div id='content'>
                <p id='para'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div id='footer'></div>
        </div>

        <script src='../../qunit/qunit.js'></script>
        <script src='../lib/traverse.js'></script>
        <script src='../lib/lumen.js'></script>
        <script src='features.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    function toArray(list) {
        var array = [],
            len = list.length,
            i = 0;

        while (i < len) {
            array[i] = list[i];
            i += 1;
        }

        return array;
    }

    function Traverse() {

        var that = this;

        this.allTags = function (node) {
            var context  = node || document.body,
                children = [],
                array = [],
                len,
                i = 0;

            children = toArray(context.childNodes);
            len = children.length;

            while (i < len) {
                if (children[i].nodeType === 1) {
                    array.push(children[i]);
                    array = array.concat(that.allTags(children[i]));
                }

                i += 1;
            }

            return array;
        };

    }

    var foo = new Traverse();
    window.Traverse = foo.allTags;

}());

alert(Traverse());
```

Now, this setup would work just fine when I passed `document.getElementById('wrapper')` to the traversal function, but when I leave it to use `document.body` it only gets two of the `script` elements. I tested this on Chrome 20.0.1132.34, Firefox 11.0, and IE 9 and they all had the same results. Through testing I did discover that the algorithm doesn't pass anything up, the `childNodes` property on `document.body` gives a length of 10 and when I turn it to an array and alert it the output is text, div, text, div, text, div, text, script, text, script. Can any of you explain why `childNodes` is not picking up the last two script tags? Thank you!

Comment: What script is this code in? `traverse.js`?

Comment: @MattMcDonald indubitably, good sir.

Comment: Your code is operating before the other two scripts have been parsed. Placing the `traverse` script before the end tag of the `<body>` element will solve this problem without the "need" for fancy events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time you call the traverse script, the other 2 scripts don't exist yet. Call traverse on domready.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log(Traverse());
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems obvious now . . . I shouldn't try to problem solve so early in the morning. XD